# how to add javascript for date picker in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to date picker widget for my view in ASP.net mvc project.here i created a java script as mentioned below but i could not able to get the date picker when i run the application. kindly help me.

java script used

```
$(document).ready(
  function () {$("#datepicker").mdatepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true       }); }
```

html code for view :

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JavaScriptdatpickr.js")"></script>
```

```
<div class="editor-label" name="datepicker" id="datepicker">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Registereddate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" name="datepicker" id="datepicker">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Registereddate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Registereddate)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called `'mdatepicker'` change this `$("#datepicker").mdatepicker` to this `$("#datepicker").datepicker` and instead of applying `datepicker` on `div` apply on `#Registereddate` as shown :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#Registereddate").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true      
   });
});
```

Comment: i tried both of your suggestions,but it is not working sadly.Kindly help further to have the date picker in my page.

Comment: @ramki_ramakrishnan...just change  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Registereddate) with  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Registereddate) and try..

Comment: i Don't know,its still not working.i have changed it to TextBox,but its still not working.

Comment: @ramki_ramakrishnan...just press f12 in browser and see in console tab ..if its showing some error??

Comment: you are really awesome,there are two console errors captured.

Comment: The errors are :Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function JavaScriptdatpickr.js:4
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:1034/34d939a88a9640fca4140744dad74685/arterySignalR/ping?r…calhost%3A1034%2Fcustomerlogin%2Fcreate&browserName=Chrome&_=1410006421180

Comment: @ramki_ramakrishnan..yes just remove 3rd jquery i.e JavaScriptdatpickr.js its not required and check..

Comment: I am getting this same error if i am removing the 3rd jquery.This time i was using Script as mentioned following.           <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(
              function () {
                  $("#Registereddate").datepicker({
                      changeMonth: true,
                      changeYear: true
                  });             }           );
        </script>                                                                         and console error is pointing to #Registeredate,saying "Undefined is not a function"

Comment: Please help me further.please

Comment: @ramki_ramakrishnan...my answer should work absolutely fine.. how can i find what is the problem sitting at my place.. i can just guide you which i did in above comments... well just check that your js files is loading properly or not through developer tools..

Comment: @kartikeya...IF i am using Datepicker for simple text field in html,its working fine.but the same code is not working for model class.that is ,i am feeding the date picker value to model class variable as you can see from the above code.please help me.

Comment: @ramki_ramakrishnan...try using textboxfor instead of editorfor

Answer (score 0):

Try below code if you want to bind datepicker value to Registerddate field:

```
$(function() {
  $('#Registereddate').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry it is not working out for me .could you please help me little further to resolve my problem.

Comment: @ramki_ramakrishnan yes.